# apply a transformation with function inline

Tags: haskell

Starting from a simple case of "fold" (I used (+) but can be anything else):

```
Prelude.foldl (+) 0 [10,20,30]
```

is it possible apply an inline transformation similar to (that doesn't work):

```
Prelude.foldl ((+) . (\x -> read x :: Int)) 0 ["10","20","30"]
```

In case not, is there an alternative to fold, to apply a generic function and inline transformation (apart from using specific functions like 'sum', 'max' etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `read` lambda applies to the first argument and the first argument to the function given to `foldl` is the accumulator. Those two arguments are the opposite for `foldr`. So, expanded, it looks like this:

```
foldl (\acc element -> (read acc :: Int) + element) 0 ["10", "20", "30"]
```

Since `acc` is an `Int`, this doesn't work.

So, with this information in hand, you can do this with `foldr` since it has the opposite argument order:

```
foldr ((+) . (read :: String -> Int)) 0 ["10","20","30"]
```

If you want an inline `foldl` version, you can use `flip` to achieve this.

You could also use `map` first (everything else being equal, this would be the solution I'd prefer):

```
foldl (+) 0 $ map (read :: String -> Int) ["10","20","30"]
```

Also, [you probably want `foldl'` instead of `foldl`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl').

Comment: thank you very much. I started with fold + map then I tried to "merge" both. Why do you think is better to keep separated foldl and map? Readability?

Comment: Yes, readability. Build your code from simple building blocks, and leave the rest to the compiler. Since GHC 7.10, it should be able to fuse these two functions, so no intermediate list is allocated.